# Changing Image Upload Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, upload

I want to create a name for the Image uploaded that will be stored as a variable Instead of

```
("ProfilePictures\\" + ProfilePicUpload.FileName));
```

I want to have something like

```
("ProfilePictures\\" + fileName));
```

So that i can name the images however I like without hard coding it.
Whenever I try to do it it creates some GuoSavEE type file.

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = "abc";
        ProfilePicUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("ProfilePictures\\" + fileName));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Will not having a file extension affect it?

Comment: Not clear what *problem* you have with this code - it seem to be doing exactly what you described...

Comment: Although, i dont know the reason behind manually renaming the filename.I would still recommend having a random GUID being generated for every image is far better which gets stored in database.